# tr utility - add exceptions to bracket expression [[:punct:]]

Tags: regex, linux, expression, tr

I was wondering if there was a simple way to add exceptions to the `[[:punct:]]` bracket expression when using [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) utility:

```
cat *.txt | tr '[[:punct:]]' '\012'
```

for instance: do not do anything if the punctuation characters are **-** or **)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead: `'(?![-)])[[:punct:]]'`

This will first check whether the next character is neither a `-`nor a `)`, and then check it for whether it's a punctuation character. Using a negative look-behind is also possible and might or might not be faster: `'[[:punct:]](?<![-)])'`

edit: since tr apparently doesn't support Regex (only basic POSIX), you should use another utility, e.g. sed: `cat *.txt | sed -r 's/(?![\-@\/\\¤%+[&|=^\]$_*#])[[:punct:]]/\012/g'`

Comment: Thanks Njol, that's perfect

Comment: done. Just a little things: it says "range-endpoints of '[-)' are in reverse collating sequence order". Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Negative lookahead in `tr`?

Comment: @bobylapointe If you add more characters to the `[]` you'll have to make sure that the minus sign is either at the start or end, or is escaped with a backslash.

Comment: No I am not talking about that (and I fully aware of that). I am saying that question was about `tr` and there is not lookaround support in sed, tr etc.

Comment: @Njol ALright, no more error message but it doesn't seem to work either: `echo bo+by | tr '(?![\-@/\¤%+[&|=^]$_*#]) [[:punct:]]' '\012'          `   it still deletes the "+" character

Comment: @bobylapointe I just checked the documentation and it appears that tr is a very old command that uses a very early POSIX syntax, i.e. it's impossible to use any advanced Regex features (like look-aheads), unlike e.g. Perl's tr, sorry. You could use the more advanded sed instead: `cat *.txt | sed 's/(?![\-@/\¤%+[&|=^]$_*#])[:punct:]/\012/g'` (didn't test this, you might have to use the -E flag, and/or change the \012 to non-octal form)

Comment: Even sed doesn't support lookaround.